# Laravel foreach retreiving a list from a specific array (whereIn not working)

Tags: laravel, foreach, where-in

what am i doing wrong guys ?

i'm trying to retrieve a customer list from the specific company that the user is registered

so i got the logged user and catched the company that he works for

```
@php
$stage = 1;
$company_user= Auth::user()->company;;
$related_users= $users->where('company', $company_user);
@endphp
```

then i'm trying to use a foreach to receive the customers from that specific company

```
@foreach ($customers->where('stage', $stage)->whereIn('user_registered', $related_users) as $customer)

@endforeach
```

i've tried also but no success

```
@foreach 

($customers->where('stage', $stage)->whereIn('user_registered', $related_users()->id) as $customer)

@endforeach
```

tried also but no success

```
@foreach 
($customers->where('stage', $stage)->whereIn('user_registered', array($related_users)) as $customer)

@endforeach
```

i think its just a code writting problem.. because i'm getting an object instead of a array..

all the variables are getting their values.. so i guess just the wherein clause is wrong...

can someone help? i think its a easy problem.. i'm new to laravel

Comment: You'd need to `->get()` the results first.

Comment: And also, avoid using `@php` in blade, prefer using controllers. Use `@foreach($customers as $customer)` in blade and pass that `$customers` variable to the view on you controller method. `@php` is fine only if it's a piece of code that is specific to the view and that the controller should not care about, like eventually the theme name, but that's about it.

Comment: but it has to show the logged user company.. if i do on the controller it will work ?
i'm kinda lost here..

Comment: @Skinds You can use the helper function (`auth()->user()`) in the blade. But mostly you can return your desired data from controller to the blade.